# Why does empty count down give me spaces

Tags: python

So I ran the first part of my code to identify the first letters of the lines and it works fine. The first for loop works fine counting up the strings in the list but when I try to do the same the other way around, it gives me spaces. Please help! Thanks

My code:

```
from sys import argv
import re
script, filename = argv
txt = open(filename)
lis=txt.read().splitlines()
O3=""
for line in lis:
    dict=[]
    if line[0]==">":
        O3+=line+"\n"
    elif len(line)==60:
        line.split("\n")
        O3+=line
    else:
        O3+=line+"\n"

O3=O3.splitlines()
print (O3)
dict=[]
R3=""
L3=""
for char in O3:
    R3=char[0:3]
    print (R3)
    for char2 in O3:
        L3=char2[len(O3):len(O3)-3]
        print (L3)
```

Sample File:

```
>Rosalind_0498
AAATAAA
>Rosalind_2391
AAATTTT
>Rosalind_2323
TTTTCCC
>Rosalind_0442
AAATCCC
>Rosalind_5013
GGGTGGG
```

Comment: Please update your question with the correct indentation. Python is very sensitive to indentation as are python programmers.

Comment: The first for loop doesn't seem to be doing anything different than if you just read the file? If the line begins with ">" append the line with a new line, if it's length is 60 then split and append which should error, else append the line with a new line

Comment: `L3` will always be empty the way your slicing it. That's why you get the spaces. Besides you should never reassign a builtin, like your `dict=[]`.